# Uploading a file via pyCurl

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, pycurl

I am trying to convert the following curl code into pycurl. I do not want to use requests. I need to use pycurl because requests is not fully working in my old python version.

```
curl
-X POST
-H "Accept-Language: en"
-F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg"
-F "parameters=@myparams.json"
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

Can someone please show me how to write it out in PyCurl?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20')
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [("images_file", (c.FORM_FILE, "fruitbowl.jpg"))])
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [("parameters", (c.FORM_FILE, "myparams.json"))])
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept-Language: en'])
c.perform()
c.close()
```